# Install python for 64-bit Ubuntu - trying to install mod_wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I have previously had python installed because of postfix. I then installed Django. Next, I tried to install mod_wsgi for deploying a Django application. I get this error:

make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] error 1

Apparently it is due to an older version of python. I tried to install a newer version of python but I still get the same problem. This is what I have installed:

/usr/lib/python2.4/
/usr/lib/python2.5

I am trying to specify which python installation to use when running Make for mod_wsgi.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, it seems as though I actually do have python for 64-bit. I run this command 'file /usr/bin/python2.5' and get: /usr/bin/python2.5: ELF 64-bit - Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running Ubuntu? How about just

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Try `./configure --help`. There's a --with-python option or similar.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but I had the same problem. I think there is something about libtool and pointing to a "shared" something or other.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided insufficient information, such as the dozen or so lines before that make error line. Those missing lines would show the real error. Possible causes may be that you don't have gcc installed or you don't have the 'dev' packages for either Python or Apache installed. The Apache/mod_wsgi package supports back to Python 2.3 so the versions you had would have been okay, albeit you may have to tell it which one to use now that you have multiple versions installed. Just make sure you read the official installation instructions on the mod_wsgi web site as it explains what all the dependencies are and how to build it.